# What C/C++ libraries do you find yourself using for iOS development?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, ios, open-source

There are a bunch of libraries available in C/C++ that can complement iOS development. If you use them, what do you find yourself using?

Examples, off the top of my head include STL, OpenSSL and GSOAP.

Please comment on your experience with them.

Thanks
Scott

Comment: I thought iOS apps could only be in Objective-C...

Comment: Objective-C => C + classes;
C++ => C + classes

Comment: I used to think that, too. But the compiler works for C and C++. Objective-C is just C with supporting objects and macros that expand things like @synthesize out into corresponding C prior to compilation.

Answer (score 6):

Boost is one that I've found to be handy

EDIT:
If you're not familiar with Boost, check out http://www.boost.org

It has a ton of libraries, though admittedly I haven't used the majority of them before.

Could you elaborate what type of applications you're building, and maybe I could point you towards specific Boost libraries or other external libraries?

Answer (score 2):

@jglouie mentioned Boost in general, but I wanted to mention [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) in particular.  I've used it for parsing crontab-like config files I downloaded from a website to control when events are triggered in a couple of my apps.

Answer (score 0):

CoreFoundation and CoreGraphics get used

(you're probably looking for public 3rd party libraries, but a lot of people overlook these)